# How can we set a default value of a v-text-field of vuetify in nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am new to vuejs and nuxtjs and at my company they are using vuetify. I need to set default value as 0 to v-text-field fields in the application but I cant find the to do so in the vuetify doc.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the default value `0` on the actual property bound to `v-model` from data object itself. `<v-text-field>` is just a wrapper around an html `<input>`. Hence, it will bind the data in same way how we are binding for input.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    textFieldValue: 0,
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <v-text-field v-model="textFieldValue"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) directive and just set the default value to `0` in your `data` property. Example: `<v-text-field v-model="textField" label="My Text Field/>` and in your data: `data: () => ({ textField: 0, })`

Hope it's the right answer, cheers